# Updating linear regression

Tags: r, linear-regression

I have a question about a code I wrote which should update a linear regression.

```
data<-rnorm(100,mean= 3,sd=1.8)
reg.cuve<-rep(0,length(data)-20)
x<-seq(1:20)
for(i in 20:length(data)){
  reg<-lm(data[i-19:i]~x)
  reg.curve[i]<-tail(fitted(reg),1)
}
```

the error must happen in the for loop. The error message I get is

```
Error in model.frame.default(formula = data[i - 19:i] ~ x, drop.unused.levels = TRUE) : 
  variable lengths differ (found for 'x')
```

However running all the commands for a fixed i, everything works. The original data is air pollution at hundred consecutive days. Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The colon in

```
i-19:i
```

has higher precedence than the subtraction, so for i=20, you get 20 - c(19,20) rather than (20-19):20 as you were expecting. Suitably placed brackets solve this

```
data<-rnorm(100,mean= 3,sd=1.8)
reg.curve<-rep(0,length(data)-20)
x<-seq(1:20)
for(i in 20:length(data)){
  reg<-lm(data[(i-19):i]~x)
  reg.curve[i]<-tail(fitted(reg),1)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is `[i-19:i]` which doesn't do what you think it does

For example when i = 20

```
20-19:20
[1] 1 0
```

What you need is `[(i-19):i]`

```
(20-19):20
[1]  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20
```